# css image simple gallery display

Tags: html, css

I am using this CSS for a really simple image gallery:

```
.product_container {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
.product_images {
    width:45%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.product_images .large {

}
.product_images .small img {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    width:151px;
}
```

i want to have a large image and then rows of 3 under that image, i created an example in a fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/jdd9hzqo/

when the page is resized, the small images are moving but i want them to stay in rows of 3 and resize themselves but keeping to the same size as the `.product_container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jdd9hzqo/2/

Changes to be made:

```
.product_images {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.product_images .large img {
    width:100%;
}
.product_images .small img {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/jdd9hzqo/1/

Remove `float:left;` in `.product_images .small img {`

And add:

```
.small {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

For the resize add something like `width: 30%;` in `.product_images .small img {`